# How can I get the return url from Http response in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a client applet, just  post a HTTP Request, with a callback url, like this:
`//http:url?redirect_url=MY_REDIRECT_URL`. And then it will go to the specified redirect-url with something appended, which I interest in.

How can I get the shipping-useful-info redirect url ? 
Which Java package should I use ?

Comment: Make your question more clear. If you make an HTTP request, the response will come from the same URL.

Comment: Are you writing the server or the client? Question is unclear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `HttpRequest` you can extract the originating host and port, that's all. If you want to have a callback `URL`, you need to include it in the body of your HTTP request, in an application specific manner. For example, you could use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and put it in JSON, or you could just use plain text if that's all there is in your body.

Comment: Thanks, I update my question to be more concrete.

Comment: @larmbr from your question, it looks like you are sending the `redirect_url` as part of the body of the message. How did you put it there? If you used `HttpRequest`, there are analogous methods on the server side, with the same class and library

Comment: I just encode that url in java.net.URL, then use HttpURLConnection. But it could not meet my need, I could not get the redirect url in response. Any other way?

Comment: @larmbr the response is generated by server not by client. If you nedd redirect url in the response, the server should set it not the client